# What is the outer metal/plastic box of a device called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a repair manual for an electronic device and I am  looking for a specific word to refer to the outer part of any electronic device such as a laptop/phone/camera/TV/radio... This "housing" is usually made of plastic or metal and is the part that the user touches when holding the device.

I was thinking that some options could be "housing"/"case"/"casing"/"enclosure"/"shell"/"box". What is the correct word? I am not sure about some of these as they could be used to refer to the "case" of the device itself or to a "case" that you can add on top of the device for protection/aesthetics. I am looking for a word that specifically refers to the "case" of the device itself.

Comment: Chassis - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chassis

Comment: "body" is another possibility, although it is another word with multiple meanings. If you can restrict it to a specific device that might help: terminology will vary between different devices, e.g. with a camera, "body" can mean the core part minus the removable lens and external flash and other accessories, but with phones you often see "metal bodied" or "plastic bodied" as descriptors referring to the outer part. "Case" likewise: with something like a TV it's clear, but with a camera ambiguous.

Comment: *Housing* works: [**housing** *noun (1)* **3 :** something that covers or protects: such as **a :** a case or enclosure (as for a mechanical part or an instrument)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/housing)

Comment: "Case" would probably be the most generic term.  ("Chassis" is the framework that components are attached to, often housed within a "case".)

Comment: You've listed six words, and the previous commenters have suggested many of the same words. What did the dictionary tell you? We can't decide the right word for you when there are multiple correct choices. It's your decision.

Comment: Since you say you are writing a repair manual for an electronic device, I think any word you choose of the list you provided will be understood to refer to the part that encloses the device, and not be confused to refer to some other thing.

Answer (score 1):

The cases for desktop computers are often called "towers".  Cabinets house larger computers.

The generic name is "cases" from what I have seen.

https://www.computercaselab.com/knowing-the-different-types-of-computer-cases/

This site distinguishes between various types of "towers".

Comment: "Tower" is a description of a particular type of base unit, specifically one whose height is greater that its width or depth. The computer can be described as being "housed in a tower case" but that distinguishes the style of case from the "desktop" case or any other style which may be offered. The outer part of the computer, which holds the components together and protects them from damage is, almost universally, the "case". In fact the outer part of a laptop or tablet is usually called the "case" as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Case* and *Chassis* are used pretty often as some of the comments indicate. Other similar words are tower, system unit and cabinet. Also, *holder* is often used for additional external casing especially on smaller devices like smartphones and tablets.

Comment: Chassis is wrong. That is the framework upon which components sit.

Comment: Chassis is fine. Especially wrt electronics cabinets where the panels are usually structural and also serve as mounts for knobs and buttons and internal components.

Answer (score 0):

Collins Dictionary

"A casing is a substance or object that covers something and protects it."

Device outer casing / external casing.

Examples from the net:

"Taking apart the outer casing for the LG VX5400."

"Clean the outer casing of the device (not the touchscreen)..."

"External casing dimensions are the same..."